# How to re-render index.js through a function in a different file. REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been working on react native for the last 3 months, but i have no experience when it comes to building a website in just react. I would like to know if its possible to re-render the "index.js" file, after a certain function in a different file is called? I want to know if maybe i can do this through a useState variable, lets say "firstTimeLoading", that only calls that function when its true and then that said function changes that variables state to false, so that way that function is only called once. Is it possible to use this method? Is it the best choice here? And how do i pass that varaible to another file so i can change its state?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking if state can be shared among your various pages / components? Yes via useContext. Are you asking if some function can only called once when the page / component loads? Yes via useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

Ooh thats a tricky one, i'm not that great at redux but i think redux could solve that problem. However some tricks i used which aren't great is by emitting functions that change the state in the parent. In that way does the parent rerender and the childrens rerenders aswell.

```
function changeName() {
    setState({name: "test"});
}

render(){
    return(
        <Child emitter={this.changeName} />
    )
}
```

this way does the child call changeName with the help of props and the parent later calls its function since the function "changeName" is in the props to the child.
if you want to update the whole site could you simply use this terrible call:

```
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: I've thought about the window reload method, but I'm not a big fan of that one. The first method doesn't work for me cause i import the function and i call it like this functionName(), and not as a component as u did.

Comment: if its a function then i think you need to use state manually, don't remember exactly how to do it though. Then send it to children via props and rerender the manually made state.